# Remounting DOWNLOADED volume that has been ejected?

Tags: audio, terminal, mount, eject

I see similar questions regarding remounting ejected USB drives but the solutions don't answer my question. If I have installed a .pkg that has created a volume, and then I have ejected said volume, how do I mount it again? It's no longer under /Volumes/, no longer under diskutil list, the Disk Utility UI doesn't have anything useful.

So are you just installing and uninstalling a .pkg every time? I thought there might be a command I could use to run a volume again?

Comment: What is your operating system?

Comment: Right click the pkg, select 'Show Package Contents' the dmg should be in there.